# Unknown Instruction : Sudo , when i try to build the docker image

Tags: docker, sudo

When I try to build the below docker file , i get the error "Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 12: unknown instruction: SUDO"

```
FROM jenkins
USER root
RUN apt-get -qqy update; apt-get install -qqy sudo
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN wget http://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest.tgz
RUN tar -xvzf docker-latest.tgz
RUN mv docker/* /usr/bin/
USER jenkins
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh junit git git-client ssh-slaves greenballs chucknorris ws-cleanup
sudo mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home
cd /var/jenkins_home
sudo chown -R 1000 /var/jenkins_home
```

Comment: by the this file is saved in UTF-8 encoding only in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You need to use the `RUN` instruction, just like you've done with everything else.

Comment: Or use '\' char if you want to split into several lines in your Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks @JJJ this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Below commands doesn't belong to Dockerfile syntax

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home
cd /var/jenkins_home
sudo chown -R 1000 /var/jenkins_home
```

Add the `RUN` infront of them if you wants to run them. But the good practice is to mount folder from local to container. If you are tying to map the jenkins home folder, then create `/var/jenkins_home` folder on local system & then mount to docker container with `-v` option.

You can follow given link for using docker in dockerized jenkins: https://medium.com/@manav503/how-to-build-docker-images-inside-a-jenkins-container-d59944102f30

Comment: Yes. I've already made use of RUN instruction and made use of @JJJ's comment.

Comment: This could potentially a separate question , but since you talked about mounting i'm putting this question here. When i ran the following command                         "sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \-v /private/var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \--name jenkins \madugula/jen
kins"                                                                                            It's giving Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/private/var/jenkins_home': mkdir /private/var/jenkins_home: permission denied.

Comment: the source directory `/private/var/jenkins_home` should be exist on local system before creating container.